# Coldfusion ORM: Self join

Tags: orm, coldfusion, one-to-many, coldfusion-9, self-join

I'm trying to join my pages cfc to itself to show child pages:

```
<cfproperty
    name="children"
    fieldtype="one-to-many"
    cfc="page"
    linktable="ParentAndChild"
    fkcolumn="parent"
    inversejoinColumn="child"
    mappedby="pageId"
    ormtype="string"
    lazy="true"
    missingRowIgnored="true"
>
```

I am getting the following error:

> could not retrieve collection size: [children#dev-home]

its mappedby pageid because the id column isn't used in parentandchild, its using its human readable id.

'dev-home' is the parents pageid.

The parentandchild table has two columns: 'parent' and 'child',   these hold the page id's

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your error. But I use a mapping for a self join and it works fine. These mappings are defined in the Page.cfc:

```
property
    name="Parent"
    fieldtype="many-to-one"
    cfc="Page"
    fkcolumn="fkpages"
;
property
    name="Children"
    fieldtype="one-to-many"
    cfc="Page"
    fkcolumn="fkpages"
    type="array"
    inverse="true"
    orderby="norder"
;
```

This is the data model. The checkbox means: allow null.

[image]